# Trying to downcast pointer of object in std::vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, dynamic-cast, downcast

In the constructor of one of my classes I have this line :

```
m_Projects = std::vector<parent_project>(); //m_Projects type is std::vector<parent_project>
m_Current = nullptr; //m_Current type is parent_project*
```

In a function of this same class I have this line :

```
m_Projects.push_back(local_project(TITLE, DEMO, FILE)); //local_project class derives from parent_project class.
```

In a third function of this same class I have these lines :

```
m_Current = &m_Projects[0];

if (dynamic_cast<local_project*>(m_Current))

   SetCurrentProject(dynamic_cast<model::local_univariate::local_univariate_project*>(m_Current));
```

The dynamic_cast returns a null value, but as I understand the cast would be supposed to work since m_Current is a pointer to the first element of m_Projects, which is a local_project object. I think I may be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as I understand the cast would be supposed to work since m_Current ... is a local_project object.

What you are saying would be true if the `vector` was containing pointers to `parent_project`. But as it stores objects, `parent_project` copy constructor is used to copy your `local_project(TITLE, DEMO, FILE)` object when being inserted (`push_back`) in the container and then the container stores a `parent_project`, not a `local_project`. So `m_Current` is not a `local_project` anymore...

You should change `m_Projects` to be a `std::vector<parent_project*>`. Then your dynamic cast will work.

```
m_Projects.push_back(new local_project(TITLE, DEMO, FILE));

m_Current = m_Projects[0];
```

Make sure you delete the objects when clearing your container to avoid memory leaks then. Or simply use a [unique_ptr](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [shared_ptr](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

As commented by Mark Ransom, see [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/3336423)

Comment: Exactly so. Search for "object slicing" to understand more.

Comment: Thank you to you both. I did not think about my objects being copied. As I look closer in the debugger, I now realise it (expanding the vector shows strictly some base class objects).

Comment: Should probably at least mention unique ptr, that's almost certainly more likely to be correct than raw pointers because his vector currently owns the objects.

Comment: `unique_ptr` may not be enough because it doesn't handle type erase unless you pass a deleter. `shared_ptr` will handle the deleter

Comment: @Bryan Chen I don't know what you mean. Unique pointer to base works perfectly well. The type erasure is handled by the virtual destructor which is standard practice.

Comment: @jpo38 Do not suggest shared pointer, this again changes ownership semantics of original code. Original code was value, which is unique ownership. Not non ownership, and not shared ownership.